# Javascript allocation of tilemap in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, dom

I am currently building a small turnedbased maze game. The maze is 2D and build up by tiles - much similar to Zelda map kinda games.

I have minimum 256 different tiles to select from and I will be reusing them a lot for different areas, such as buildings, trees, walls, grass, water etc.

My plan is to make it run as smooth as I can without using any other framework than jQuery for Ajax and DOM manipulation.

The game-engine is server-side, so the client browser is not performing any of the AI-logics etc. Its just requesting the "current state" of the game, then receiving the objects/enemies etc. But it has the levelmap downloaded from the start. The level could be like 256x256 tiles and each tile could be 32x32 pixels... havent decided on the block size yet, but I think thats the most optimal. Might be larger though.

The player viewport will probarbly take up around 9x9 tiles or perhaps 15x15 tiles. Then you will scroll to see action and move around.

As its turnbased, so no worries for "screen flickering 60 fps" a single flicker here and there is okay, but not all the time.

**My question is: Whats the most optimal way to generate the map in the client?**

- 1) should I transfer the map as "data" (json or similar) and then generate DIV's with CSS to build the tilemap in the client. This will minimize the bandwidth, but I fear that the DOM in the client will be at hardwork when I scroll the map?

or

- 2) should I prerender the full tilemap or larger parts (squares) of the map so that the browser has less DIV's to handle. This will kill reuseability for the maps as they are hardly patterned, so its just going to be "pure graphic download" + the tilemap information needed for the game collision etc. It ought to be faster to scroll for the browser.

I cant figure out if it will take more or less resources once downloaded with the second approach, as the client/browser will have to allocate memory for all the larger "prerendered" blocks instead. But if its the "data optimal" solution from 1) its also going to be generating a lot of DIV's with class' and render these in the browser DOM somehow.

SVG and canvas is currently not an option, unless someone can provide me with a fast way of converting alpha transparent PNGs' to canvas and still being able to scroll around with a viewport (with as many FPS as possible though, aka more than 15 fps)

Comment: I'd say first approach is more viable, what if you'll end up with an odd (say 103) size of your world, with 2x2 tiles? You'll get stuck. Even if the tiles will need to get redrawn each scroll, it shouldn't be as slow.

Comment: I will be handling the "size" of the world myself, so I can 100% control what "grid" will allowed to design the maps in. If its 16x16 tiles I will lock it at that.

Comment: But @Vesper - what if my levelmap is 256x256 tiles. Thats going to be 65536 (64K) of DIV's - can a smart phone handle that at all? (iPhone4, Samsung Galaxy S2 etc)

Comment: @BerggreenDK: option#1 is the way to go. For rendering, you don't need to have 2^16 tiles in the dom - only those the user is looking at.

Comment: What is you issue with transparent images on canvas? It should work. And notice the approach would not be much different from DOM, as you're not going to paint a 8192x8192px-cancas :-)

Comment: @Bergi - thats what my stomach feelings told me too, but isnt the DOM DIV create/destroy heavy for the browser?

Comment: Not too heavy, no. Absolutely positionized they will not trigger huge reflows, and dynamically adding/removing them is much better than having 2^16 elements in the memory :-) Have you ever looked at the DOM of, say, Google Maps or OSM?

Comment: @Bergi yeah, I know how Google Maps works. Thats why I was considering my method #2 + I have a background from Commodore 64/Amiga platform, so I know about limit ressources and powers, still being able to produce a smooth experience.

Think I will break the levelmap into smaller parts too and then download them as needed too.